# Where can I find a Lightroom lens profile for a Sigma lens?

Tags: lightroom, sigma

I can't find the lens profile for Sigma 15-30mm f/3.5-4.5 EX DG IF ASP to install in Lightroom 5.7

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Have you try to use Adobe Lens Profile downloader?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe didn't create a profile for that lens. In late 2013, a staff member at Adobe forums responded to a [similar question](https://forums.adobe.com/message/5925235#5925235) about the Sigma 15-30 DG with,

> At the time that we began the joint lens profile project with Sigma, we had to make a call as to which set of lenses to support (given the extensive lens line).  We made the decision to proceed with profiles for current lens models only.  At that time, the 15-30 had already been discontinued, so it was not included in this list.
>
> As others have noted above, the current options are (1) use Adobe Lens Profile Creator to build your own profile, or (2) to use the Adobe Lens Profile Downloader to check if someone else has already built a profile.

If somebody else has created and shared a profile of the lens, you can download it using the [Adobe Lens Profile Downloader](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/digital-negative.html#Adobe_Lens_Profile_Downloader).